# A problem on semisimple element in a lie algebra and the reductive centralizer

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let G be a semisimple algebraic group, $\mathfrak{g}$  its Lie algebra and $x ∈ \mathfrak{g}$ . The problem is  the centralizer $ZG(x)$ is reductive implies $x$ is semisimple.

I think we can reduce the case to $x$ being a nilpotent. The hint says we need the Konstant's theorem,  but I don't think it is necessary.

For the conserve statement($x$ semisimple implies $ZG(x)$ reductive),  do we need $G$ to be semisimple?

Comment: For the converse: you can increase the centralizer by adding some direct factors to the group. So, you may get counterexamples.